# Ajax : data to SQL

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I'm a newbie in AJAX.

I looked for the solution in Google, but I didn't find a working solution.

So, I want to send data from a jquery's draggable div to sql via php.

index.html :

```
<html>
[...]
<body>
<myDiv>bla bla</div>

<script>
$( "myDiv" ).draggable({ stop: function() {
var position = $(this).position();
var xPos = $(this).css('left');

$.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "update.php",
      data: xPos,
      cache: false,
      }
}
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

update.php :

```
   <?php 
    require("db.php");

             $xpos = $_POST['xPos'];
             mysql_query("UPDATE item SET pos_x = '" . $xpos . "' WHERE ID = '". $post_ID."'");

        mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
    }
    ?>​
```

db.php :

```
  <?php
    $dbhost              = "**";
    $dbuser              = "**";
    $dbpass              = "**";
    $dbname              = "**";

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("Error connecting to mysql");
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
    ?>​
```

Could someone tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: The pronoun "I" is always capitalised in English. What is the problem? Why do you think something is "wrong"? What happens when you run your code?

Comment: Your `update.php` contains a syntax error; why is `}` there? You also have no SQL injection prevention whatsoever; why not?

Comment: i smell sql injection. i hope you have magic_quotes_gpc on [to make this clear: i don't encourage anyone to use magic_quotes_gpc instead of proper programming]

Comment: @lawl0r: It's 2011. I hope that _nobody_ has `magic_quotes_gps` on.

Comment: You're also missing `);` after the braces on the `cache: false` line in your js. And where is `$post_ID` defined in your php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply a named attribute for `$_POST['xPos']` to work. Change this in your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "update.php",
      data: xPos, // Change this to --> data: 'xPos=' + xPos,
      cache: false,
      }
} // <-- get rid of this
});
```

Few errors in your update.php:

```
         // if xPos is not defined it could throw an error.
         // make sure you do if (isset($_POST['xPos'])) { [...below code here...] }
         $xpos = $_POST['xPos']; 

         // !! sql injection warning!!
         // change to mysql_real_escape_string($xpos),
         //           mysql_real_escape_string($post_ID) ..... etc.
         // also where is $post_ID defined? If this is a magic variable, naughty!
         // always use the global magic variables $_POST $_GET, etc.
         mysql_query("UPDATE item SET pos_x = '" . $xpos . "' WHERE ID = '". $post_ID."'");


    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
}
?>​
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. The "$post_ID" variable is already declared in my complete code.